# Magento 2 load phtml file through Ajax in admin panel

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, template, ajax

I am trying to load phtml file though ajax in admin panel. Can one please suggest right way to approach that.

```
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('Magento\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Category')
                    ->setTemplate('Magento_Test::ajax.phtml');
$block->assign([
    'swatchid' => "Hello"
]);
if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax')) {
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory` in your controller instead of the `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory`:

```
$resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
$resultLayout->addHandle('LAYOUT_HANDLE');

return $resultLayout;
```

Then make the layout file : **{module_dir}/view/adminhtml/layout/LAYOUT_HANDLE.xml**
and define the layout:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <block class="Magento\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Category" name="some.block" template="Magento_Test::ajax.phtml"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```